# Joining two models to obtain data

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I query my model like so

```
$projects = Project::where('status', '!=', 'Completed')->get();
```

This will return me something like this

```
#attributes: array:16 [▼
    "id" => "7"
    "user_id" => "32"
    "contactEmail" => "sdfsdf@dsfsdf.com"
    "deploymentDate" => "2016-07-29"
    "status" => "Starting"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2016-07-12 14:12:32"
    "updated_at" => "2016-07-15 09:47:34"
]
```

I then pass this model to generate an Excel file

```
Excel::create('projects', function($excel) use($projects) {
    $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($projects) {
        $sheet->fromArray($projects);
    });
})->export('xls');
```

Everything works fine, and the Excel is generated.  One problem I have though is that the excel file shows user_id being 32.  Instead of displaying the user_id, I want to display the userName which is 
part of my Users table.

How can I join these two tables to get the name instead of the id?  All relationships are set up correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
$projects = Project::select('product.*','users.name AS user_name')
            ->leftjoin('users','product.user_id','=','users.id')
            ->where('status', '!=', 'Completed')->get();
```

Using this code you will be able to get `user_name` for more relationship please refer [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)